# How to map IEnumerable<Model> to a DTO with IEnumerable<AnotherDto> property using automapper?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, automapper

I have these model and DTOs

```
public class ServiceModel
{
    public string ServiceId { get; set; }
    public string ServiceName { get; set; }
    
    public string ServiceTypeId { get; set; }
    public double QuarterlyCharge { get; set; }
    public double AnnualCharge { get; set; }
}

public class ServiceResponseDto
{
    public string ServiceId { get; set; }
    public string ServiceName { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<TaxDto> Tax { get; set; }
}

public class TaxDto
{
    public string ServiceTypeId { get; set; }
    public double QuarterlyCharge { get; set; }
    public double AnnualCharge { get; set; }
}
```

I have IEnumerable of ServiceModel resulting into:

| ServiceId | ServiceName | ServiceTypeId | AnnualCharge | QuarterlyChar |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Service | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | Service | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 1 | Service | 3 | 3 | 3 |

How do I map it into ServiceResponseDto

This is my current solution

```
IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, ServiceModel>> groupedservice = serviceQueryResult.GroupBy(c => c.ServiceId);
ServiceResponseDto mappedService = _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, ServiceModel>>, ServiceResponseDto >(groupedservice );
```

My mapping:

```
CreateMap<IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, ServiceModel>>, ServiceResponseDto>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.ServiceId, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.FirstOrDefault().Key))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.ServiceName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.FirstOrDefault().FirstOrDefault().ServiceName))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Tax , opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Select(c => new TaxDto() { ServiceTypeId  = c.FirstOrDefault().ServiceTypeId , QuarterlyCharge = c.FirstOrDefault().QuarterlyCharge, AnnualCharge  = c.FirstOrDefault().AnnualCharge } )));
```

Expected Result:

```
new ServiceResponseDto()
{
    ServiceId  = "1",
    ServiceName = "Service"
    Tax = new IEnumerable<TaxDto>()
    {
        new = TaxDto(){ServiceTypeId=ServiceType1, QuarterlyCharge =1, AnnualCharge=1},
        new = TaxDto(){ServiceTypeId=ServiceType2, QuarterlyCharge =2, AnnualCharge=2},
        new = TaxDto(){ServiceTypeId=ServiceType3, QuarterlyCharge =3, AnnualCharge=3},
    }
}
```

Actual Result: Only 1 record shows up after mapping

```
new ServiceResponseDto()
{
    ServiceId  = "1",
    ServiceName = "Service"
    Tax = new IEnumerable<TaxDto>()
    {
        new = TaxDto(){ServiceTypeId=ServiceType1, QuarterlyCharge =1, AnnualCharge=1}
    }
}
```

Comment: Unrelated: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730019/why-not-use-double-or-float-to-represent-currency

Comment: I'll take this into cosideration @Fildor

Comment: You create a map from `IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, ServiceModel>>` to a single `ServiceResponseDto`. I think you want to define a map for `IGrouping<string, ServiceModel>` to `ServiceResponseDto` (Automapper will then take care of the rest)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically you created a mapping from an `IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, ServiceModel>>` to a single `ServiceModel`. But you seem to instead want to create a map for `IGrouping<string, ServiceModel>` to a `ServiceModel`.

So change your mapping to:

```
CreateMap<IGrouping<string, ServiceModel>, ServiceResponseDto>()
  .ForMember(dest => dest.ServiceId, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Key))
  .ForMember(dest => dest.ServiceName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.FirstOrDefault().ServiceName))
  .ForMember(dest => dest.Tax, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Select(c => new TaxDto() { ServiceTypeId = c.ServiceTypeId, QuarterlyCharge = c.QuarterlyCharge, AnnualCharge = c.AnnualCharge })));
```

And then in code call:

```
var mappedServices = mapper.Map<IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, ServiceModel>>, IEnumerable<ServiceResponseDto>>(groupedServices);
```

Keep in mind though that since you started with a `IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, ServiceModel>>` you'll end up with an `IEnumerable<ServiceResponseDto>`

See it in action here:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/YzIlDt

Hope this helps and good luck on your project!

Comment: I kinda fixed my own problem. This works by the looks of it thanks